# How do I scrape all Twitter followers using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

I'm trying to scrape all Twitter followers from my profile and then save it to a text file, but I don't know where to look to do this effectively as I'm novice at Python.

What am I doing wrong? :(

[See here. This is what I want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLQbl.png)

This is the code:

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    sleep(5)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
   

    
    for twusernames in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Timeline: Followers"]//a[@role="link"]'):
        print(twusernames.get_property('href'))
        file = open("usernames.txt", "a")
        file.write(twusernames.get_property('href'))
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
```

So what it does is - it scrolls down so that new followers are loaded and then scrape them, but it's messed up. It picks up other unnecessary links too, and it misses some followers.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Consider using the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api) instead. This will be more robust than trying to scrape this information.

Comment: That depends. They did not accept my request. :(

Comment: You want to scroll all the way down and then scrape.